# Error with Django fields ["'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Can everyone be helpful in this situation:
I have a project in pythonanywhere host.
I created models and register in admin.But after make migrations command I write migrate and have this error:
 File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1399, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

There is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    passw = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    regdate = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug', 'price', 'available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_editable = ['price', 'available']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

please, somebody explain me my mistake.I stuck with this.....Thanks a lot!!!!!!!

Comment: You are getting an invalid value error. That must mean that the format of the date you are entering is wrong. Also, you should probably inherit from the existing user class in Django to make your own User class as it becomes much easier and even encrypts the users passwords.

Comment: Try by adding the null and blank arguments in Datetime Fields in models.py: `models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) ` and retry the migration.

Comment: THANKS a lot!!!!Help to add blank=True in this field!!!!!